# How to test if a user has a role within a service implementation in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I know I can add the RequiresAnyRole or RequiresRole attribute on my service:

```
    [RequiresAnyRole("Admin", "HeadChaperone")]
    public GuestChaperoneResponse Delete(DeleteGuestChaperone request)
    {
        bool hasHeadChaperoneRole = ??
    }
```

But how can I test within the service implementation if the user has a certain role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for roles in your Service with:

```
GetSession().HasRole(roleName,AuthRepository)
```